# jQuery and progress bar for synchronous functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar, synchronous

I want to display progress bar on a html site.
As most of loading time is due some processing in a loop, I tried:

```
var func = function(){
    var myList = []
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        $("#progress_bar").html("Progress: " + i "/100");
        myList = push(some_function(i));
    }
    return myList;
}
```

However, I see only result for `i=99`.
If it weren't inside a function, I would just use iteration based on `window.setTimeout` but here it would make `func` returning `undefined`.

Is there a way, in JavaScript, to have at the same time:

- function returning result,
- html progress bar being updated as the function proceeds?

Comment: Perhaps the loop is iterating really fast, and hence you only see the last value. Try logging `i` and see how fast it is progressing.

Comment: @levi Each iteration lasts for ~200ms. There is no problem with logging - it happen in the real time. However, displaying - not. I tried `setTimeout` - it solves displaying but does not work with returning value.